# How do I get into the Fort Frolic atrium?

Tags: bioshock

Note: This is about entering the Fort Frolic atrium for the *first* time, not about getting into the upper level, which seems to be the most prominent issue people encounter.

After Sander Cohen talked to me and sent spider splicers my way, I dispatched them. It seems that I'm supposed to go advance into the atrium now, but the doors are still closed. Cohen isn't talking anymore and there are no living spider splicers to be seen or heard. I've checked guides like [this one](http://guides.gamepressure.com/bioshock/guide.asp?ID=3332) and it doesn't seem like I should need to do anything else...

I've tried leaving the area and coming back but nothing happens. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1):

It's a glitch I believe. I fought with my back near the door and only four spider splicers jumped down. Reload and move about. You should have six spider splicers jump after you.

Comment: But how do I unglitch it?

Comment: I would restart the level since it happens early on.

Comment: I don't have that option. I checked and for some reason the last save prior to that was 2 days beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found it already there is a button next to the elevator on the left. That lets you inside

Comment: Do you have an image for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Replaying on PS4 & came across this issue as well.  I restarted from a previous save, moved out of Hephaestus right after Cohen's speech and wove myself between the newly appeared electric wires.  Waited to kill all 6 of the spider splicers once they fell/attacked but the doors remained closed.  Traveled back to Arcada, took a short walk, traveled back to Fort Frolic and immediately new dialogue from Cohen started.  The doors are now open.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem. Somehow an enemy is not triggerd or stuck. In went in for me when i was fighting at the doors. You could try that. Greetz

Answer (score -2):

Smash window with two First aid kits. Thus triggering bots and cohen to talk

Comment: This is incorrect.